# gpg batch-encryption with my own key without keyboard interaction

Tags: bash, encryption, gnupg

I need to save a couple of files on a webserver and would like to have them encrypted with my own public key before.

Therefore I just wrote a simple bash-script:

```
#!/bin/bash  

ls *.7z > filelist.txt

while read currow
do
 gpg --encrypt -ac --recipient myemail@example.com $currow

done < filelist.txt
rm filelist.txt
```

But this doesn't really work. For each file I get this dialog where I have to enter my password (twice).

[image: pinentry]

How can I avoid this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `-c` option, which is the short equivalent of the long `--symmetric` option. You are *not* using public key cryptography by using this option, which is why you are asked for a password.

Try changing `-ac` to `-a` in your script above.

Comment: Ooops! You are right. I was in the assumption the ´-c´ option would prevent the Umlaute from disappearing. Many thanks